# Journey Builder contacts not getting evaluated

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created Journey with data extension as entry source and which updates Contacts and Custom object records , using values from data extension, however i do not see contacts entering in journey after i scheduled the JB  it says 0 contacts evaluated, 0 entered Journey. any Leads highly appreciated.

Comment: Some more details around this-
 Entry Data Extension is populated with 5 records.
Created Journey and use this Data Extension as Entry.  Set to “New Records Only, on first run, read All Records”
Activate Journey and schedule to Run.
Journey runs but 5 records are not injected.

NOTE:  This journey does not send email, it updates Sales Cloud records.
Are there specific requirements for Entry Data Extension to get new subscribers injected?  Does it need subscriber key?  Does it need primary key?

Our subscriber key is Contact Id.

Comment: Is your data extension have a `SUBSCRIBER RELATIONSHIP`?  Is contact id the primary key?

Comment: Yes , it has subscriber relationship, contactid is not the primary key. however i tried to make another ID field as Primary , and it still did not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Journey Settings and Contact Entry. If you have the settings on `No re-entry` then the contacts will not enter back into the journey.

[image: Journey Settings]

Journey Builder has what is called a "high water mark." The data extension you are using may not be detecting new rows because new data was not added to the data extensions.

The high water mark tracks the last event processed for the event source data extensions. Only records above this high water mark will be processed and records below this high water mark will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a very common problem, I'll answer this question even if it's pretty old..

Jackson's answer is partially correct. I'll add a second part..

Your problem can be related to the **high water mark** OR the **Contact Evaluation config**. You said JB says *0 contacts evaluated* and *0 contacts accepted*.

When you select "**Evaluate new records only**", JB will only evaluate new records that come after the high water mark.

When you select "**Evaluate all records**", JB will evaluate all contacts on your DE and accpet them or not **depending** on your **Contact entry settings** (and filter criteria on contacts if you have any).

So in your case, since no contact was evaluated, I suppose you chosed the first option.

[image]